# Set Default Admin Colour For All Users

Tags: admin, wp-admin

I am surprised with the new colour scheme for 3.8 and although the classic 3.7 theme has gone, I would like to set the new "Light" colour scheme as the default for all users, but at the same time, still allow them to change the theme if they wish, in their user profile.

Has anyone managed to come up with a function to set the default for all users?  I've searched but can find nothing as this is so new, 3.8 codex not fully written.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set (in terms of force) a default color within `functions.php` like this:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_admin_color', 'update_user_option_admin_color', 5 );

function update_user_option_admin_color( $color_scheme ) {
    $color_scheme = 'light';

    return $color_scheme;
}
```

Update: The following color schemes are available per default at WP 3.8

- fresh
- light
- blue
- coffee
- ectoplasm
- midnight
- ocean
- sunrise

Bonus (found on [wpmudev](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-how-to-remove-admin-color-scheme-options-in-wordpress/)): Disable the Admin Color Scheme Options to make sure that users can not switch back to another color:

```
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );
```

Update 2: As Rarst pointed out the filter above will **force** a specific color scheme instead of setting a changeable default. The solution to this is to run an action only once (e.g. on user setup/registration) so after that the user can decide and change the color on his own:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

       update_user_meta($user_id, 'admin_color', 'light');

}
```

Update 3: Okay, so one more try :)

The idea is to add extra user meta data (see `custom_admin_color_scheme`) as soon as the user updates the profile; as long as the field is not set to `true` we'll change the default admin color scheme to a color scheme of our choice:

```
// add custom user meta data
add_action('personal_options_update', 'save_custom_admin_color_optios');
function save_custom_admin_color_optios( $user_id ) {

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'custom_admin_color_scheme', true);

}

// change default color scheme if not customized
$customized_color_scheme = get_user_option( 'custom_admin_color_scheme', get_current_user_id() );
if ( empty($customized_color_scheme) ) {

    update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'admin_color', 'light');

}
```

Update 4: Finally there is also a very nice plugin on wordpress.org to handle default admin color schemes easily: [Default Admin Color Scheme](http://wordpress.org/plugins/default-admin-color-scheme/)

Comment: Won't this **force** specific scheme rather than set change-able default?

Comment: @Rarst Good point! I updated my answer and added an action to only change the color on setup; after that it's up to the user :)

Comment: Actually - this is not very helpful for users already registered. I don't suppose there is a way to actually force them to make a choice on next login (that would be a lot of work I guess).

Comment: @Sol Simply check if there is already a setting and if it is one of the predefined color schemes from 3.8. If now, just `exit( wp_redirect( admin_url( 'profile.php' ) ) );` (not sure about `profile.php`) redirect them to their profile and add an `admin_notice` that they should change. Done this way, they're forced as the redirect will happen until this setting is done :)

Comment: Hi Kaiser, sounds perfect are you able to provide an example code?

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer one more time; now the defaults are switched to a scheme of our choice, as long as the user has not updated the color scheme manually. Hope this will do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

the `add_filter( 'get_user_option_admin_color', ...)` sets the color, but it doesn't remove the option from my-profile page. So, if you want to enforce (and block) any modification by user:

```
    remove_action("admin_color_scheme_picker", "admin_color_scheme_picker");
```

If you also need to set that when user registers, then :

```
add_action('user_register', 'my_func');
function my_func($user_id) {
    $args = array(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'admin_color' => 'ectoplasm'
    );
    wp_update_user( $args );
}
```