# Get current active wp color scheme

Tags: admin

Is there a way to return the current active color scheme?

This is how to register a new admin color scheme

```
<?php register_admin_color_schemes(); ?>
```

is there something like `get_admin_color_scheme();` that will return which is active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current admin color scheme is a user setting, you can get its value with:

```
$current_color = get_user_option( 'admin_color' );
```

See the function `admin_color_scheme_picker()` in `wp-admin/includes/misc.php` for an usage example.

Comment: Is there a possibility to actually **GET** the styles? The implementation in `wp-admin/includes/misc.php` uses a global variable called  `$_wp_admin_css_colors` which is `null` when I try to access it...

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access the colors in PHP, you have to do a little trick. In the file from [toschos answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127402/31527) they use the global variable `$_wp_admin_css_colors`. This gets destroyed at any point of the runtime.

I actually found the right hook to copy it:

```
<?php
    $admin_colors;
    add_action('admin_head', function(){global $_wp_admin_css_colors; $admin_colors = $_wp_admin_css_colors;});
?>
```

So now I can access the colors at any point in the script I want like this:

```
$admin_colors[get_user_option('admin_color')]['colors']; // array(0 => #222, 1 => #333, 2 => #0074a2, 3 => #2ea2cc)
```

Here is an excerpt of `$admin_colors` to demonstrate the structure:

```
$admin_colors = Array
(
    [fresh] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Default
        [url] => https://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/css/colors.min.css
        [colors] => Array
        (
            [0] => #222
            [1] => #333
            [2] => #0074a2
            [3] => #2ea2cc
        )
        [icon_colors] => Array
        (
            [base] => #999
            [focus] => #2ea2cc
            [current] => #fff
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: What if we want to add a new color scheme combination to the list and not simply access the list. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not particular sure, but I _think_ WP has an API for registering color schemes. But it might work, though, if you change `$_wp_admin_css_colors` first.

Comment: You probably try an earlier hook as well, as this only exports, as the admin header gets loaded and thus could be too late

Comment: That was it.  I didn't know the function existed.  Thanks!

Comment: Which function do you mean? And how exactly did you solve it

Comment: My apologies.  The wp_admin_css_color() function helps us extend the color scheme base that comes with Wordpress. We can create our own color schemes easily with that function.   I had a couple developers help me out with that here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244982/hooking-into-register-admin-color-schemes

Answer (score 2):

Every user can set his own admin color scheme, so you can also get the color scheme according to an user ID:

```
get_user_option( 'admin_color', get_current_user_id() );
```

Further reading: [WP 3.8 Default Admin Colour For All Users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126697/wp-3-8-default-admin-colour-for-all-users/126700#126700)

Comment: You don’t need `get_current_user_id()`, that’s the default.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simple way to get the current admin color scheme or set it also, see the code:

**Set the default admin color scheme**:

```
<?php

/**
 * Set the default admin color scheme for WordPress user.
 */
add_filter('get_user_option_admin_color', 'set_default_admin_color');
function set_default_admin_color($result)
{

    // set new default admin color scheme
    $result = 'midnight';

    // return the new default color
    return $result;

}
```

**Get the current admin color scheme**:

```
/**
 * Get the current admin color scheme from WordPress user.
 */
add_filter('get_user_option_admin_color', 'get_current_admin_color');
function get_current_admin_color($result)
{

    global $_wp_admin_css_colors;

    // get current admin color scheme name
    $current_color_scheme = $result;

    // get all available colors from scheme name
    $colors = $_wp_admin_css_colors[$current_color_scheme];

    // now you can use this colors or store it
    // var_dump($colors);

    // important: we should return the default color scheme
    return $result;

 }
```

**Get all available admin colors schemes**:

```
/**
 * Get all available admin colors schemes from WordPress user.
 */
add_filter('get_user_option_admin_color', 'get_all_admin_colors');
function get_all_admin_colors($result)
{

    global $_wp_admin_css_colors;

    // get all available color schemes
    $colors = $_wp_admin_css_colors;

    // now you can use this color schemes or store it
    // var_dump($colors);

    // important: we should return the default color scheme
    return $result;

}
```

@see gist here also: https://gist.github.com/mohamdio/bb9a1a18446aca257935846d217060e9